# Why do some umask values not take effect?

Tags: permissions, umask

I'm trying to understand permissions better, so I'm doing some "exercises". Here's a sequence of commands that I'm using with their respective output:

```
$ umask
0022
$ touch file1
$ ls -l file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 0 Mar 16 12:55 file1
$ mkdir dir1
$ ls -ld dir1
drwxr-xr-x 2 user group 4096 Mar 16 12:55 dir1
```

That makes sense because we know that the default file permissions are `666` (`rw-rw-rw-`) and directories default permissions are `777` (`rwxrwxrwx`).
If I subtract the umask value from these default permissions I have
`666-022=644`, `rw-r--r--`, for the `file1`, so it's coherent with the previous output;
`777-022=755`, `rwx-r-x-r-x`, for the `dir1`, also coherent.

But if I change the umask from `022` to `021` it isn't any more.

Here is the example for the file:

```
$ umask 0021
$ touch file2
$ ls -l file2
-rw-r--rw- user group 0 Mar 16 13:33 file2
```

`-rw-r--rw-` is `646` but it should be `666-021=645`. So it doesn't work according to the previous computation.

Here is the example for the directory:

```
$ touch dir2
$ ls -ld dir2
drwxr-xrw- 2 user group 4096 Mar 16 13:35 dir2
```

`drwxr-xrw-` is `756`, `777-021=756`. So in this case the result is coherent with the previous computation.

I've read the man but I haven't found anything about this behaviour.

Can somebody explain why?

**EXPLANATION**

As pointed out in the answers: `umask`'s value is not *mathematically subtracted* from default directory and file's permissions.

The operation effectively involved is a combination of AND (&) and NOT (!) boolean operators. Given:

**R** = resulting permissions
**D** = default permissions
**U** = current umask

**R = D & !U**

For example:

```
666& !0053 = 110 110 110 & 
            !000 101 011 
             110 110 110 &  
             111 010 100
           = 110 010 100 = 624 = rw--w-r--
```

```
777& !0022 = 111 111 111 & 
            !000 010 010
             111 111 111 &  
             111 101 101
           = 111 101 101 = 755 = rwxr--xr-x
```

**TIP**

An easy way to quickly know the resulting permissions (at least it helped me) is to think that we can use just 3 decimal values:

```
r = 100 = 4 
w = 010 = 2
x = 001 = 1
```

Permissions will be a combination of these 3 values.
 `" "` is used to indicate that the relative permission is not given.

```
666 = 4+2+" "   4+2+" "   4+2+" "  = rw rw rw
```

So if my current umask is `0053` I know I'm removing read and execution `(4+1)`  permission from group and write and execution `(2+1)` from other resulting in

```
 4+2     " "+2+" "     4+" "+" "   = 624 = rw--w-r--
```

(group and other already hadn't execution permission)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`umask` is a *mask*, it’s not a subtracted value. Thus:

- mode 666, mask 022: the result is 666 & ~022, *i.e.* 666 & 755, which is 644;
- mode 666, mask 021: the result is 666 & ~021, *i.e.* 666 & 756, which is 646.

Think of the bits involved. 6 in a mode means bits 1 and 2 are set, read and write. 2 in a mask masks bit 1, the write bit. 1 in a mask masks bit 0, the execute bit.

Another way to represent this is to look at the permissions in text form. 666 is `rw-rw-rw-`; 022 is `----w--w-`; 021 is `----w---x`. The mask drops its set bits from the mode, so `rw-rw-rw-` masked by `----w--w-` becomes `rw-r--r--`, masked by `----w---x` becomes `rw-r--rw-`.

Answer (score 12):

You need to think in binary, not decimal.  Specifically, there are three 3-bit binary numbers: one each for Owner, Group, and Other. Each with values ranging from 000 to 111 (0-7 in decimal).

e.g. rw-rw-rw (666) is 110 110 110.

The `umask` value is a mask specifying which bits will be on or off (1 or 0) when creating a new file or directory.  e.g. 022 decimal is 000 010 010 binary, while 021 decimal is 000 010 001

The permission bits are AND-ed together with the negated umask to arrive at the final value.  "negated" means that all bits are inverted, i.e. all 1s flipped to 0, and vice-versa.  e.g. `NOT 022 (000 010 010) = 755 (111 101 101)`

Example: `666 & !022 = 644`.  In binary, that's:

```
  Owner  Group  Other     mode
   110    110    110      666 
&  111    101    101      755   (this is the negated 022)
   ---    ---    ---      ---
   110    100    100      644
```

Also, `777 & !022 = 755`:

```
  Owner  Group  Other     mode
   111    111    111      777 
&  111    101    101      755
   ---    ---    ---      ---
   111    101    101      755
```

Note how the final value of each bit can only be 1 if it is 1 in **both** the original permission value (666 or 777) **AND** in the negated umask.  If either of them is 0, the result is 0.  That is, *1 & 1 = 1*, while *1 & 0 = 0*.

---

Strictly speaking there's a fourth 3-bit binary number for the setuid, setgid, and sticky bits.  That's why you often see permissions and masks specified with a leading 0 (or some other leading number from 0-7).  e.g. 0777 or 2755.